# inc instruction changes next one value in an array

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I declare this array:

```
array dw 10 dup(0)
```

But when I want to increase a value with this:

```
mov bx, 5
inc array[bx]
```

It changes next one by 256 and the correct value by 1:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7XZ8.png)

[image]

Comment: The index `bx` counts bytes, not words.  If you want to increment the 5th word, `bx` needs to be 10.  386 and higher has "scaled" mode where you can do `[array + bx*2]` but 8086 does not.

Comment: @NateEldredge: minor correction: 16-bit address size (even in 32-bit mode) still uses the same 8086 encoding of ModRM (with no optional SIB), so `[array + bx*2]` is never legal.  `mov ebx, 5` / `inc word [array + ebx*2]` would be, though.  This makes some sense if you think about binary compat for 386 running existing 16-bit code, and building the decoder hardware to handle the old vs. new modrm encodings: being able to use the new encoding with the old size is an extra combination that actual x86 avoids needing to handle in protected mode.  And certainly real mode has to be binary compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array initializes these 20 bytes in memory:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The instructions

```
mov bx, 5
inc array[bx]
```

will change the array to

```
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

because `BX` is used as an offset measured in bytes from the start of the array.

The screenshot that you've posted is easily created from trying to visualize the word-sized elements from the array **but incrementing by 1 the pointer that is used in the algorithm instead of raising that pointer by 2 which would be correct**.

```
0,0                         0:
  0,0                       0:
    0,0                     0:
      0,0                   0:
        0,1               256: 
          1,0               1:
            0,0             0:
              0,0           0:
                0,0         0:
                  0,0       0:
                    0,0     0:
```

Verify if this is the case...